# FQL Query iOS - Error 1

Tags: ios, facebook-fql

I'm trying to run a FQL query on iOS. The table that i'm querying is event_member. It's like this:

> SELECT eid,start_time FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() AND start_time >= '2013-07-02 13:01:57  0000' AND start_time <= '2013-07-09 18:01:57  0000'

This leads to error 1, but I don't know why. Can Someone Help Me?

Answer (score 0):

Your date values are wrong - even if the time zone offset is zero, a `+` is still required before it:

```
start_time >= '2013-07-02T13:01:57+0000' AND
start_time <= '2013-07-09T18:01:57+0000'
```

(The `T` in there between the date and time part should also be present if I read [ISO8601 (resp. what Wikipedia makes of it)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) correctly here, but Facebook does not seem to be so strict about *that*.)